# 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Tags: .net, wpf, events, wpf-controls

I have a WPF UserControl in which I try to implement the **custom** MouseClick (because *there is no `MouseClick` event on a WPF (User)Control*) event.

I got the following:

[image]

Some code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Occurs when users left clicks the MyControl.
/// </summary>
public event MouseButtonEventHandler MouseClick { add { AddHandler(MouseClickEvent, value); } remove { RemoveHandler(MouseClickEvent, value); } }

    protected virtual void OnMouseClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.RaiseEvent(e);
        //this.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MouseClickEvent, this));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        if (!this.movedAfterMouseDown)
        {
            OnMouseClick(e);
        }
        this.gotLeftButtonDown = false;
        this.movedAfterMouseDown = false;
    }
```

So, where is the problem?

## UPDATE 1

```
protected virtual void OnMouseClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //base.RaiseEvent(e);
    MouseButtonEventArgs args = new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.ChangedButton);
    this.RaiseEvent(args);
}
```

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: routedEvent

[image]

## UPDATE 2

An other custom event I implemented successfully (work without problems) - `SelectedChanged`:

```
static void OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var s = (MyControl)source;

    s.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(SelectedChangedEvent, s));
}
```

## UPDATE 3

System.Windows.Controls.Control's OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick implementation:

```
protected virtual void OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.RaiseEvent(e);
}
```

## Update 5 (for people in the tank)

```
class Foo : FrameworkElement
{
    event EasterCameEvent; // I named it MouseClick

    public DoSomething()
    {
        EasterCameArgs args= ...

        if (Date.Now = EasterDate)
            OnEasterCame(args)
    }

    protected virtual void OnEasterCame(EasterCameArgs e)
    {
        base.RaiseEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the title containing SO.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the base.RaiseEvent(e) from ALL parts of your custom user control. That is the cause of the stack overflow.

If you're inheriting from UserControl, the click events are already implemented for you. You do NOT need to re-implement. You MAY need to handle them though, but most probably you do not.

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // handle the event if you need to do something with the data.
    // this is not over-riding the event, this is attaching a custom handler to the event
    this.gotLeftButtonDown = false;
    this.movedAfterMouseDown = false;
}
```

This does not over-ride the event. This is a handler for when the event is raised! Users of your control will write handlers just like this one. Don't reimplement it. Don't even handle it unless you need to do something with the data. These events are written for you already.

Edit:

While my answer was wrong in that it didn't fix the issue, it should still be helpful to understand WHY the stackoverflow exception was happening.

```
protected virtual void OnMouseClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.RaiseEvent(e);
    /* this will raise the OnMouseLeftButtonUp event if the MouseButtonEventArgs
       designates that it came from the MouseLeftButtonUp event. 
       That will then call the OnMouseLeftButtonUp because e.RoutedEvent equals
       MouseLeftButtonUpEvent.

       The accepted answer does the following, to stop OnMouseLeftButtonUp being
       called again, and the whole process repeating itself in an infinite loop.

       args.RoutedEvent = MouseClickEvent;
       base.RaiseEvent(e); // No longer fires MouseLeftButtonUp, breaking cycle.

       // Changes the event to be fired, avoiding the cycle of
       // OnMouseLeftButtonUp -> OnMouseClick -> OnMouseLeftButtonUp etc
    */
}

protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
    if (!this.movedAfterMouseDown)
    {
        OnMouseClick(e); // This will call OnMouseClick handler
    }
    this.gotLeftButtonDown = false;
    this.movedAfterMouseDown = false;
}
```

The control flow was:

1. User generates MouseLeftButtonUpEvent
2. OnMouseClick is called within OnMouseLeftButtonUp handler
3. OnMouseClick raises MouseLeftButtonUp event
4. Goto 2.

The accepted answer changes to this:

1. User generates MouseLeftButtonUpEvent
2. OnMouseClick is called within OnMouseLeftButtonUp handler
3. OnMouseClick changes the routed event to MouseClickEvent
4. OnMouseClick raises MouseClickEvent
5. Control resumes

This is what I was trying to explain in comments on other answers. If I wasn't clear enough I apologise for that. I believe that serhio and I were out of sync in that I was trying to explain the cause of the stackvoverflow, when he was looking for a fix to the code. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: sorry to disappoint you, but there is no MouseClick implemented on WPF user controls.

Comment: +1. @serhio: What's the difference between DoStuff and OnMouseClick? Nothing! That's what's going on here.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Come on, pleople. I call in the **OnMouseClick** method that DOES NOT EXIST in the base class, the *different* **RaiseEvent** mehtod that EXISTS. You write me about the same DoStuff

Comment: -1 make difference between **`protected override`** OVERRIDE and **`protected virtual`** DECLARATION

Comment: @serhio: We understand that there is a difference. That doesn't change the fact that raising that event there is causing your handler to be called again. Frankly, what you're trying to do as a whole does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Billy, my control tries to say to the world: "hey, people, a MouseClick event occured on Me". MyControl generates *by itself* a  ***totally custom event***  named `MouseClick`. I could name it "MyFrikinEvent", but I just named it "MouseClick".

Comment: @serhio, the problem was not raising the OnMouseClick, but re-raising OnMouseLeftButtonUp during the MouseClick, since you were generating the MouseClick event from MouseLeftButtonUp.

Comment: @Josh Smeaton: No, there was any problem, because my MouseClick does not generate any other event. see the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's in this line:

```
base.RaiseEvent(e);
```

If you are handling the mouse click you don't want to raise the event again as that will simply call your handler again, which will raise the event....

Comment: Instead of `base.RaiseEvent(e)` you should probably use `base.OnMouseClick(e)`.

BTW, I believe you should be able to take a look at some of the call stack in the debugger to see the recursive calls.

Comment: @Colin Thomsen: e... man, there is no base.OnMouseClick in a WPF UserControl. This is why I declared one in my custom `MouseClick` event.

Comment: @serhio - What are you trying to achieve by re-raising the event?

Comment: @ChrisF: I just try to raise my `MouseClick` event. I don't want to re-raise anything

Comment: Right, sorry, I misread the code. The comment about viewing the callstack in the debugger is still valid.

Comment: @Serhio: Don't use the tooltip, use the real call stack viewer.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: doubt that this will help on the exception matter :)

Comment: @Serhio: For the stack overflow you should see a truncated stack if you use the Call Stack Window.

Comment: @Colin: ?base.RaiseEvent(e)
Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.

Comment: @Serhio: Go to 'Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack' to see the Call Stack Window.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected virtual void OnMouseClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MouseButtonEventArgs args = new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.ChangedButton);

    // Don't forget this
    args.RoutedEvent = MouseClickEvent;

    base.RaiseEvent(args);
}
```

Comment: So, it *was* re-raising itself over and over? By setting the routedevent property, you trigger a completely different event rather than the same.

Comment: @Josh: this will raise the event only once: `base.RaiseEvent(args);` base.RaiseEvent does never call OnMouse, because doesn't know of its existence.

Comment: We're talking about two completely different things. My problem wasn't with this method here. It was with the OnLeftButtonUp handler. That calls OnMouseClick which in turn calls OnLeftButtonUp again. You may have fixed the issue, but do you understand why it was breaking?

Comment: It clearly DOES call OnMouseClick inside the IF block checking if mouse moved. Not raising the event, but it directly calls OnMouseClick. You might want to reconsider calling people dummies when they haven't insulted you first. The reason the answer here works, is because the OnMouseClick is CHANGING what event is fired when base.raiseevent is called. Before, it was just calling OnLeftXXX again.